# Android-apt-compiler :[] error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name ''

Tags: android, android-theme

I opened an existing project that work fine in Android Studio 2.1 Beta 2 and I have some errors when I run the project.

The style fields are:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
    Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
    res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
    backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>

<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>

<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>
```

And in the `AndroidManifest.xml` I have the reference for the theme like this:

```
 <application
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

The errors are:

> Error:(7, -1) android-apt-compiler: [mobile]
>   C:\mobile\trunk\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving
>   parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name
>   '@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
>
> Error:(7, -1) android-apt-compiler: [mobile] C:\mobile\trunk\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving
>   parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name
>   '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
>
> Error:(8, -1) android-apt-compiler: [mobile] C:\mobile\trunk\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving
>   parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name
>   '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light'.

I tried several methods to solve this errors but without success. Please help me someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my errors. 
I had added the correct dependencies for android-support-v7-appcompat in the ProjectStructure->Modules->MyProjectName ->add dependencies. 
Work fine now.

Answer (score 0):

The styles actually are coming from the `AppCompat` support library, which I assume are in your gradle dependencies.

Try changing the theme style declarations to

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>

<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>

<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>
```

Also when dealing with studio upgrades:

- Run > gradle > run with the task `clean`
- File > Invalidate Caches/Restart -> Invalidate Cached and Restart
- Make the project

It will throw out ALL old builds and artifacts and do a clean build instead of incremental. Sometimes resources get out of sync and this solves it.

Comment: @Derk-Jam Your solution still does not solve my problems. The errors are the same.

Comment: @ruru I'm on 2.1

In module -> `build.gradle` >>> 
`compileSdkVersion 23`
`buildToolsVersion "24rc2"`
`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'`

In top-level -> `build.gradle` >>>
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'`

Comment: I can`t have the build folder because i can`t run the project.

Comment: I understand, these files are not in the build folder.

Comment: How to add this build.gradle file to my project or what is the path to this file?

Comment: build.gradle with `compileSdkVersion`, `buildToolsVersion` and the `appcompat` declaration are in `/PROJECT/app/build.gradle`. The `classpath` declaration is in `/PROJECT/build.gradle`. Also, time to upgrade your studio to 2.1.1.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but in the meantime i solve my errors.

Comment: What I said is adding the dependency. You should accept your own answer as the solution.